# Find dates that are not on the first or last day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `Locations` that has column named `effective_date` with many dates from many years, and I want to retrieve only those that are ***not*** on the first day of the month or the last day of that month.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to receive help you need to display your own attempts at solving the problem. In other words http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Comment: Sounds good, will work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `effective_date` columns is of type `date`, then this SQL query will return all rows with a non-null `effective_date` value that is other than the 1st or last day of the month:

```
select t.effective_date , count(*)
from dbo.foo t
where 1 = 1 -- just for clarity
  -- after the 1st day of the month
  and t.effective_date > dateadd(day                 ,
                           1-day( t.effective_date ) ,
                                  t.effective_date
                           )
  -- and prior to the last day of the month
  and t.effective_date < dateadd( day                                ,
                           -day( dateadd(month,1,t.effective_date) ) , 
                                 dateadd(month,1,t.effective_date)
                           )
```

If your column carries a time component with it, that is, any of:

- `datetime`
- `smalldatetime`
- `datetime2`
- `datetimeoffset`

You'll want to cover your bases and modify the query, something like

```
select *
from dbo.foo t
where 1=1 -- added for clarity
  -- effective date on or after the 2nd of the month
  and t.effective_date >= convert(date,
                            dateadd(day                 ,
                              2-day( t.effective_date ) ,
                                     t.effective_date
                              )
                            )
  -- and prior to the last day of the month
  and t.effective_date < convert(date,
                           dateadd(day,
                             -day( dateadd(month,1,t.effective_date) ) ,
                                   dateadd(month,1,t.effective_date)
                             )
                           )
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas Carey! I did not have all the time in the world yesterday to get through all of this page, but it seems like your query is working really well. Now just to pick this apart... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae56d/3/0) with the detail below.

Generate a table and some sample test data:

```
CREATE TABLE Locations(
   effective_date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Locations
  VALUES('2014-01-01') -- First day so we would expect this NOT to be returned
INSERT INTO Locations
  VALUES('2014-01-02') -- This should be returned
INSERT INTO Locations
  VALUES('2014-01-31') -- Last day of January so this should NOT be returned
```

Then the query below works out the last day of the month for each date in the table, records are only returned is if the `effective_date` is not the first or last day of the month as calculated.

```
SELECT effective_date FROM Locations
 WHERE -- not the first day (the easy bit!)
   DATEPART(day, effective_date) <> 1 
       -- not the last day (slightly more complex)
   AND DATEPART(day, effective_date) <> 
       DATEPART(day, DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,effective_date)+1,0)))
```

When executed only `January, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000` is returned as expected.

The clever bit here is the function to calculate the last day of the current month when given a date, lets examine that and break it down:

```
DECLARE @sampleDate DATETIME
SET @sampleDate = '2014-01-02'

-- Calculate the number of months between '1900-01-01' and the @sampleDate
-- +1 as we want to shift into the following month so we can work back:
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,0,@sampleDate) + 1
-- Result --> 1369

-- Create a new date by adding the result of the previous step in
--  months to '1900-01-01'
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@sampleDate)+1,0)
-- Result --> '2014-02-01' (giving first day of the following month)

-- Subtract one second from this
SELECT DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@sampleDate)+1,0))
-- Result --> '2014-01-31 23:59:59' (giving the very end of the original month) 

-- Finally extract the day of the month
SELECT DATEPART(day, DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@sampleDate)+1,0)))
-- Result --> 31
```

Comment: threw it in SQL dbx and worked like a charm!!! Thanks so much. Saved me and the company hours of my trying to learn this!!!

Comment: @user3689016 you do know that "saving me from learning this" doesn't sound good? What if the next time you have a similar issue again

Comment: I have been trying to find the answer to this for the last few hours and I am not a DBA, but I have taken a DB class, so it took me a good half hour just to pick apart the date diff and date add functions. I was trying to learn it and I still have to tweak it a bit, so I am sure that I will learn from it now that I can see it! I will definitely pick it apart to be able to tweak it to our needs but, it helped from having to learn the functions myself. Most of the things I found on the web had simplified versions of the functions, and did not have all of the parameters for me to learn.

Comment: It just saved me a few hours of time, just in learning the functions. I had not even looked at the DATEPART function yet, and for someone like me who uses sql at work for simple queries, this helped tremendously. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 but please don't advocate shorthand like `s`, `m`, etc. If you mean `SECOND`, type `SECOND`. [Please read](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, your article is an interesting read. That is what makes StackOverflow so good - we are always learning! I have updated my answer and removed the abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

The first day of the month will always be 1.

You should be able to adapt this to find the last day of the current month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

Source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Comment: [Please see my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941910/find-dates-that-are-not-on-the-first-or-last-day-of-the-month#comment36885961_23942852).

Comment: @Aaron I just copied that from the article I cited. I typically prefer readability over being concise as your blog post advocates.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL to display dates in a month for only first & last day. Also display dates in month excluding first & last day.

```
declare @EndOfMonth  as DateTime 
set @EndOfMonth = (  SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) )
select @EndOfMonth as EndOfMonths

declare @EndOfMonthMinus1  as DateTime 
set @EndOfMonthMinus1 = (SELECT DATEAdd(DAY, -1, @EndOfMonth) )
select @EndOfMonthMinus1 as EndOfMonths

declare @BeginingOfMonth  as DateTime 
set @BeginingOfMonth  = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101))
select @BeginingOfMonth  as EndOfMonths  

declare @BeginingOfMonthPlus1  as DateTime 
set @BeginingOfMonthPlus1 = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-2),GETDATE()),101))
select @BeginingOfMonthPlus1 as EndOfMonths   

-- select dates in month exclude first and last day 
SELECT TOP 1000 [effective_date]
FROM [Locations]
where effective_date <= @EndOfMonthMinus1
  and effective_date >= @BeginingOfMonthPlus1  

-- select only first of month and last of month
SELECT TOP 1000 [effective_date]
FROM [Locations]
where [effective_date]<= @EndOfMonth
and [effective_date] >= @EndOfMonthMinus1
    and [effective_date] >= @BeginingOfMonth
    and [effective_date] <= @BeginingOfMonthPlus1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Please see my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941910/find-dates-that-are-not-on-the-first-or-last-day-of-the-month#comment36885961_23942852).